# Getting network error when trying to check the run history of the workflows properties

Tags: visual-studio

Getting network error when trying to check the run history  of the workflows  able to get the response through postman but iam unable to see t run history of the workflow can you help me in this concern

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHs05.png)